# Is there a difference between "bitte noch" and "bitte"?

Tags: meaning, difference

I've seen *bitte noch* used in several places where it seems to mean the same thing as *bitte*. Does the *noch* convey any meaning or emotion? For example: *Kannst du bitte das Geschirr abtrocknen?* vs. *Kannst du bitte noch das Geschirr abtrocknen?* (Example from Wiktionary).

Comment: Z.B. [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/noch) zeigt die Bedeutung von "noch" doch ganz gut, oder nicht?

Answer (score 1):

"Bitte noch" is not a combined idiom. "noch" or "auch noch" implies that it's in addition to something else, whereas "bitte" is a singular request. So sure if you're making multiple requests you could use both "bitte" or "bitte noch" but the "noch" is rather unrelated to the bitte and more related to the amount of requests.

Answer (score 0):

"bitte" and "noch" do not group up like that.

You can take out the "bitte" in both versions and the sentences are the same, except without "please". So "bitte" vs "bitte noch" is not a thing.

I'm sure you'll find an answer to what "noch" means on this forum.
Here's one option:

[Meaning of "noch" in context](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8622/meaning-of-noch-in-context)

Comment: In the example I gave, Google translate gives the same result with and without the *noch*. So was the example wrong? If not then I still don't understand what the function of the *noch* was.

Comment: @RDBury In the sentence as in the OP, the "noch" (DE) should IMHO be translated as "also" (EN)

Comment: @planetmaker: Okay, I guess that answers the question then.